# How is async/await working in serial and parallel?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have two `async` functions. Both of them are waiting for two 3 seconds function calls. But the second one is faster than the first. I think the faster one is running in parallel and other in serial. Is my assumption correct? If yes, why is this happening as both the functions look logically same?

```
function sleep() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
}

async function serial() {
  await sleep();
  await sleep();
}

async function parallel() {
  var a = sleep();
  var b = sleep();
  await a;
  await b;
}

serial().then(() => {
  console.log("6 seconds over");
});

parallel().then(() => {
  console.log("3 seconds over");
});
```

Comment: Why do you think `setTimeout` is async? There's nothing async in your code except function declarations.

Comment: @Mjh Errm, `setTimeout` is by it's very nature asynchronous...and pretty much everything else in OP's code is asynchronous as well...

Comment: @Frxstrem except `setTimeout` is not asynchronous at all. It's a synchronous function that tells the event loop to execute a function at a later time. It's a *mechanism*, there's absolutely NOTHING asynchronous in this code. Which two moving parts are moving at different speeds, in different execution contexts? Zero. Hence, this code isn't async at all.

Comment: @Mjh The main context, the callback to `setTimeout`, both `serial` and `parallel`, and the callbacks to both calls to `.then`, all run in different executing contexts.

Comment: @Frxstrem this all works in the same thread, the execution context is not different, there are no two moving parts, the function in question `setTimeout` is synchronous. Emulating the mechanism of async behaviour does not mean something is async. But hey, if you prefer to believe it is - I'm just a mere mortal telling you a story you don't like.

Comment: @Mjh, This is what exactly "async/asynchronous" means in javascript. They need not be running in multiple threads. Though currently javascript allows using background threads.

Comment: @Vadakkumpadath whatever rocks your world, if you can't make out the difference between *mechanism* that notifies the thread with event loop and actual, asynchronous operations then ok, excellent, let's make that async in javascript world :)

Comment: @Mjh We are using the term "async/asynchronous" because in javascript that's the official word for it. "asynchronous programming" is the term used by ECMAScript 2017 language specification. https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/

Comment: @Vadakkumpadath why would you explain what async is when, obviously, I'm more than familiar with the term, spec and obviously how it works behind the scenes. There's a difference between a mechanism of async (the way event loop gets its notifications) and actual async code. You're currently just using the mechanism via synchronous code. Sure, you can emulate the behavior. But, your code _is not_ asynchronous. Now, I'll stop because no one is going to budge so it's best we leave it be as it is.

Comment: @Mjh It's been nice talking with you..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Frxstream already has [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479579/263693). To build on that, and provide some perspective:

The first thing to recognize is that Promises are created "hot" - that is, by the time you have a promise object, it is already "in progress".

The second important concept is that `await` is like an "asynchronous wait" - that is, it pauses the execution of the function until that promise completes.

So, the `serial` function calls `sleep`, gets a promise back, and then (asynchronously) waits for that promise to complete. After that promise completes 3 seconds later, `serial` again calls `sleep`, gets a promise back, and then (asynchronously) waits for that promise to complete. After that promise completes 3 seconds later, `serial` completes.

The `parallel` function calls `sleep` and stores its promise in `a`, and then calls `sleep` and stores its promise in `b`, and then (asynchronously) waits for `a` to complete. After `a` completes 3 seconds later, `parallel` (asynchronously) waits for `b` to complete. After `b` completes practically immediately, `parallel` completes.

Answer (score 10):

It's clearer if you write your `serial` function like this:

```
async function serial() {
  var a = sleep(); //
  await a;         // await sleep();

  var b = sleep(); //
  await b;         // await sleep();
}

async function parallel() {
  var a = sleep();
  var b = sleep();
  await a;
  await b;
}
```

Here you can clearly see that in the `serial` function, the second `sleep()` is only called after the first `sleep()` has completed, while in `parallel` it's called immediately, before the first has completed, and then it waits for both to complete. So while they may *look* functionally identical, they are subtly different.

Comment: Mind if you took a look from the perspective of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889290/919480 ?

Comment: @cogitoergosum - I think Frxstrem was just explaining the difference you asked about in your question, not suggesting that you should necessarily do it that way. `serial` above is fine if you want the operations running in series (one after the other). `parallel` above is indeed better implemented as `await Promise.all([sleep(), sleep()]);` but again, I don't think that's the point of the answer above. The point of the answer above (I think) is to explain the timing difference in the question.

Comment: Also, `var a = sleep(); var b = sleep(); await a; await b;` works just the same.

Answer (score 3):

Because the`sleep()`function is a synchronous function, it just return a asynchronous promise, eg:

```
function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

In `parallel()`, the two `sleep()` synchronously init two promise，they wait to be resolved meanwhile, it's going to be about 3s.

However, in `serial()`, the two `await sleep()` means that the second `sleep()` promise must wait for the first `sleep()` to be resolved, so it's going to be about 6s.

Answer (score 1):

**Serial Run:** Run the functions one after another

```
//  It’s slow! and use only for serial(one after another) run
async function doThings() {
    const thing1 = await asyncThing1(); // waits until resolved/rejected
    console.log(thing1);

    const thing2 = await asyncThing2(); // starts only after asyncThing1() has finished.
    console.log(thing2);
}

doThings();
```

**Parallel Run:** Run the functions parallel

```
// ✅ async code is run in parallel!
async function doThings() {
    const p1 = asyncThing1(); // runs parallel
    const p2 = asyncThing2(); // runs parallel


    // Method 1: Prefer => Promise.all()
    const [resultThing1, resultThing2] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]); // waits for all 
    // the promises get resolved or fails fast (If one of the promises supplied to it 
    // rejects, then the entire thing rejects).

    // Method 2: Not-Preferred
    const resultThing1 = await p1;
    const resultThing2 = await p2;

    console.log(resultThing1); // reaches here only after both the p1 & p2 have completed.
    console.log(resultThing2);
}

doThings();
```