# async await Promise.all with chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a few promise functions that I would like to do a promise.all on with async await. However i'm not sure how to do it when there is a 'then' chain in one of them.

For example.

```
Promise.all([
    promiseFn1(),
    promiseFn2().then(promiseFn3)
])
```

How would I implement async await when `promiseFn2()` is chained inside a `Promise.all`?

I'm thinking of making an annoynmous function but would prefer not to:

```
await Promise.all([
   promise1.fn(),
   (() =>{ 
       p2response = await promise2Fn(); 
       return promise3Fn(p2response);
   })()
])
```

Comment: `Promise.all([
    promiseFn1(),
    promiseFn3(await promiseFn2())
])`?

Comment: Move `promiseFn3()` into `then()` inside `promiseFn2()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, [that can lead to unhandled rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation)

Comment: @Bergi it's exactly the same as in the first example, no need to be so pedantic.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I guess the pedantry is necessary then, as `promiseFn3(await promiseFn2())` does behave differently than `promiseFn2().then(promiseFn3)`. Consider the case where `promiseFn1()` rejects - it's a subtle but important distinction.

Comment: That makes sense. So in your answer, it's different because the helper function converts the thrown error into a rejection, allowing `Promise.all()` to prioritize failing on the `promiseFn1()` as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an immediately executed `async` function expression could do this:

```
await Promise.all([
    promise1.fn(),
    (async () => promise3Fn(await promise2Fn()) )()
])
```

However I would recommend to stay with the much simpler `.then()` call. It's not like anything forces you to use `await` everywhere…

Alternatively, if you are looking for clean code (and the `then` chain isn't as simple as in your example but involves function expressions), just use a named helper function:

```
async function promise2and3fn() {
    return promise3Fn(await promise2Fn());
}
await Promise.all([
    promise1.fn(),
    promise2and3fn()
])
```

There's no way around these extra functions when you want to use `await` concurrently, as execution inside a function is always sequential.

Comment: I agree, the `.then()` call is a lot easier to read than that other nonsense.

Comment: my example has greatly simplified promise2 & 3, hence I was wondering if there was a clean way to write it. Might have to just name it as a function. Ty