# JavaScript/Angular 1 - Promise.all to async-await

Tags: javascript, angularjs, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I assign two calls to the web service in two variables in `referencesPromise` and `contactTypesPromise` `$onInit()` (I can create a new method for that, if needed)

```
$onInit() {
  const referencesPromise = this.ReferenceService.getMultipleReferences(this.AgentReferences)
  const contactTypesPromise = this.ContactService.getContactTypes()
  Promise.all([referencesPromise, contactTypesPromise]).then((responses) => {
    this.references = responses[0]
    this.contactTypes = responses[1]
    const stateParams = this.$state.params
    return this.setContactSteps()
  })
}
```

What is his alternative with async-await?

Comment: you want onInit to be async/await?

Comment: @zabusa Yes, or create a new method for that

Comment: you can call async function inside onInit()

Comment: @zabusa if I move the logic on a new method?

Comment: (for AngularJS) you should be using [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) instead of `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you still want your methods to run concurrently there aren't too many changes to make:

```
async $onInit() {
  const referencesPromise = this.ReferenceService.getMultipleReferences(this.AgentReferences);
  const contactTypesPromise = this.ContactService.getContactTypes();

  this.references = await referencesPromise;
  this.contactTypes = await contactTypesPromise;
  const stateParams = this.$state.params;
  return this.setContactSteps();
}
```

Note how the initial calls are the same, we still want to capture the promises as we want both requests to run at the same time.

Comment: Please note a slight difference in semantics since you do not use the "all" combinator: If only the contactTypesPromise is rejected, this would still assign the "references" variable which it does not do with the "all" combinator.

Comment: Good point - if the original "if one blows up it should all blow up" error handling is desirable it can be recreated with a try catch.

Comment: [You must not do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation)

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for `Promise.all` in `async`/`await` syntax. It still works on promises, it's sugar for `then` calls only.

So use

```
async $onInit() {
  const referencesPromise = this.ReferenceService.getMultipleReferences(this.AgentReferences)
  const contactTypesPromise = this.ContactService.getContactTypes()
  const responses = await Promise.all([referencesPromise, contactTypesPromise])
  this.references = responses[0]
  this.contactTypes = responses[1]
  const stateParams = this.$state.params
  return this.setContactSteps()
}
```

(this works a bit different than your original code which did not `return` anything from `$onInit`, not sure whether that was intentional - an `async` function always returns a promise)

Answer (score -1):

You can use $q.all() for the alternate of your need as per the given example as shown below,

```
$q.all([this.ReferenceService.getMultipleReferences(this.AgentReferences), this.ContactService.getContactTypes()]).then(function(result) {
    this.referencesPromise = result[0];
    this.contactTypesPromise = result[1];
    this.stateParams = this.$state.params;
    return this.setContactSteps();
});
```