# Printing the resolved value of a JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am learning about the JavaScript `async / await` API, and implementing the [example code from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Simple_example)

In one section, detailing the differences between `async/await` and `promise.then()`, the following is written:

```
var resolveAfter2Seconds = function() {
  console.log("starting slow promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(20);
      console.log("slow promise is done");
    }, 2000);
  });
};

var parallel = function() {
  console.log('==PARALLEL with Promise.then==');
  resolveAfter2Seconds().then((message)=>console.log(message)); 
  // in this case could be simply written as console.log(resolveAfter2Seconds());

}

setTimeout(parallel, 10000);
```

I was suspicious about the bit that says

> // in this case could be simply written as
>   console.log(resolveAfter2Seconds())

So, I ran the code and got the following:

```
starting slow promise
Promise { <pending> }
slow promise is done
```

Is the MDN example code comment trying to imply that instead of `Promise { <pending> }`, I should see `20`? Why?

Comment: The example code comment looks completely wrong.

Comment: This looks like a typo in the docs - could potentially write `console.log(await resolveAfter2Seconds())` - you should make a change request

Comment: @Michael that'd be exciting, but I'm not sure that code works. I tried `console.log( await resolveAfter2Seconds());` and got `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @CalebJay: you can only `await` inside of an `async function`.

Comment: @Jacob oh right, and my previous version of this comment was me missing another syntax error; This works:  `var trythis = async function(){
    console.log(await resolveAfter2Seconds());
}

trythis();`

Comment: Yeah, that page doesn't look good. They also don't show an example of `await Promise.all(…)` and feature the [concurrent-`await`s antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation).

Comment: you could do this: `.then(console.log)`