# Promise#all vs sequential awaits - difference in time resolution

Tags: javascript, time, promise, async-await

In the following snippet the resolution time is different when using promise#all and sequentially await for each promise. I want to deeply understand what is going on, since it seems to be a caveat when dealing with performance.

*Edit: added another case with no function invocation, probably I am missing something with how await works

```js
// Code goes here

window.onload = function() {
  
    let p = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res('p OK')
        }, 5000);
    })
   
    let p2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res('p2 OK')
        }, 5000);
    })
    
    let p3 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res('p3 OK')
        }, 5000);
    })
  
    async function pp() {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res('pp OK');
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
  
    async function a() {
        let out = await Promise.all([p, pp()]);
        return `#a ${out}`;
    }
  
    async function b() {
       let out1 = await p;
       let out2 = await pp();
       return `#b ${out1} ${out2}`;
    }
    
    async function c() {
        let out1 = await p;
        let out2 = await p2;
        let out3 = await p3;
        return `#c ${out1} ${out2} ${out3}`;
    }
  
    let out1 = document.getElementById("out1");
    let out2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    let out32 = document.getElementById("out2");
    const date = new Date().getSeconds();
    a().then(x => console.log(x)).then(() => out1.innerHTML += `finished after ${new Date().getSeconds() - date}s`);
    b().then(x => console.log(x)).then(() => out2.innerHTML += `finished after ${new Date().getSeconds() - date}s`);
    c().then(x => console.log(x)).then(() => out3.innerHTML += `finished after ${new Date().getSeconds() - date}s`);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="out1">
        Promise#all  
    </p>
    <p id="out2">
        Sequential awaits
    </p>
    <p id="out3">
        Sequential awaits without executing fnc
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation

Answer (score 2):

Some points that may clarify things:

- The constructor callback function that is passed to `new Promise` is executed *immediately*, meaning the `setTimeout` delay kicks in at *that* moment, whether you are going to await it or not.
- By consequence, the timeouts created by `p`, `p2` and `p3` are all initiated as soon as those variables are initialised. As they all will time out after 5 seconds, the corresponding promises (`p`, `p2` and `p3`) will get resolved at about the same time. Again, this is *independent* on whether you use `await`, `then`, `Promise.all` or just forget about those promises and don't do anything with them.
- By contrast, the function `pp` is just a function. It is not a promise. Only when you actually *call* that function, you create a promise with the corresponding timeout that initiates.
- `await` makes the `async` function return *immediately*, returning a promise. This means that the rest of the function's code is postponed, but not the rest of your other Javascript code: the function returns and execution continues after that function call. When the call stack is empty, the different event queues will be processed. So it is not blocking. Once the promise that was passed to `await` resolves, something magically happens: the `async`'s function execution context is *restored* and the execution resumes until the next `await`. If there is no more `await` to execute, and the function gets to its end, the promise it returned (when it encountered the first `await`) is *resolved*.
- `Promise.all` does not influence when the individual promises resolve. It creates a new promise that resolves when *all* the given promises have resolved. As explained above, the promises in your case (`p`, `p2`) resolve at about the same moment, so `Promise.all` will also resolve after about 5 seconds.
- If you do `await pp()` you only create that promise there and then, not earlier. And because you have an `await p` before it, it will take 5 seconds before `pp()` is executed. So the corresponding timeout does not start *until* this second `await` is executed. That is why `await p; await pp()` takes twice 5 seconds to resolve.
- The case is different when you do `await p; await p2`. There both promises already were created, and their timeouts already started. So when after 5 seconds the first `await` is over, JS will get to the second `await` and will find that `p2` is also resolved. There will not be any extra waiting period (except for the asynchronous management where `await` will always put an event in the microtask queue)

I think with these elements you can correctly picture how the code will execute, and how the output you get is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, it executes `pp` straight away to start the promise timeout.
In the second function, it waits until `p` has been completed before it executes `pp` to start the promise timeout.

The `await` keyword "blocks*" execution until the promise resolves before continuing on to the next line.

RE: the update

In your third example, all the promises are started at the time. The `await` keyword waits until the promise is resolved. Because all your promises start at the same time, they will all resolve within a very small delta. By the time you hit `await p2`, it's likely already resolved. Same for `p3`.

In your second example, `pp` doesn't start until `p` completes.

[*] It doesn't really block execution, but that's the impact it has on your code.

Comment: can you please check the updated snippet? I have included a function c awaiting 3 promises which returns after 5 seconds as well. It is not blocked in any way. Thank you

Comment: can you please elaborate on why the promises in the last example are started at the same time?

Comment: Because they are all created at the same time. The promise under `pp` is only created when the function is called.