# How to make parallel async / await api callouts

Tags: javascript, async-await

Im new to Async / Await and trying to make these 3 callouts to get Google Drive metadata in parallel using Node.js.
The 3 callouts are: `rootFolder`, `folders`, `files`.

Since these call upon the `getGdriveList` function which itself is an async function and includes an `await`. The `await` is needed as the API returns a page of records and I need to loop through all the pages to get the records. I use the `await` to await the API response and add the data to an array. This process renders the code to run in series.

I am looking for help to refactor to make this parallel. Thanks in advance

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const gOAuth = require('./googleOAuth')
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

// initialize google oauth credentenatials 
let readCredentials = gOAuth.readOauthDetails('credentials.json')
let authorized = gOAuth.authorize(readCredentials, getGfiles)

// get Google meta data on files and folders
function getGfiles(auth) {
  let rootFolder = getGdriveList(auth, {corpora: 'user', 
                                        fields: 'files(name, parents)', 
                                        q: "'root' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"})

  let folders = getGdriveList(auth, {corpora: 'user', 
                                    fields: 'files(id,name,parents), nextPageToken', 
                                    q: "trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"})

  let files = getGdriveList(auth, {corpora: 'user', 
                                    fields: 'files(id,name,parents, mimeType), nextPageToken', 
                                    q: "trashed = false and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"})

  files.then(result => {console.log(result)})
}

const getGdriveList = async (auth, params) => {
  let list = []
  let nextPgToken
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth})
  do {
    let res = await drive.files.list(params)
    list.push(...res.data.files)
    nextPgToken = res.data.nextPageToken
    params.pageToken = nextPgToken
  }
  while (nextPgToken)
  return list
}
```

Comment: There's no `await` in `getGfiles` so these already *do* run concurrently. (You are however logging only the result from one of them, ignoring - and not waiting for - the other two. You should add a `Promise.all` for that.)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi this is great info! so to confirm, even though there is an `await` in `getGdriveList` which is utilized in each of the 3 callouts. it still is parallel?

Comment: I've just added the following to my code: 
`files.then(result => {console.log(result)})`
`folders.then(result => {console.log(result)})`
`rootFolder.then(result => {console.log(result)})`

 the first to return is `rootFolder` then `folders` then `files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially currently have:

```
const promise1 = parallelBackendWork(...);
const promise2 = parallelBackendWork(...);
const promise3 = parallelBackendWork(...);

promise3.then(result3 => {console.log(result3)});
```

You're creating 3 promises but only `.then()` on one of them. If that one *(`promise3`)* finishes first, I suspect your execution won't work as expected.

I suspect you'll want to do something to combine all 3 of those promises. This is what `Promise.all([])` is for. You might like to checkout `Promise.race([])` as well.

```
const promise1 = parallelBackendWork(...);
const promise2 = parallelBackendWork(...);
const promise3 = parallelBackendWork(...);

const promises = Promise.all([ promise1, promise2, promise3 ]);

promises.then(results => {console.log(results)});
```

*Note, `results` will be an `Array`. You probably want to use destructuring as @ATOMP suggests.*

Comment: thank you so much for helping me here! I get it, ill modify my final response to use `Promise.All()`

Comment: "*You might instead just `await` each promise…*" - no, [don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation)!

Comment: You probably do not want to use `Promise.race` in this situation.

Comment: Sure, but it's a related idea that many don't realize exists. I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @CameronTacklind 's answer, array destructuring is the more idiomatic way of doing this.

```js
const [rootFolder, folders, files] = await Promise.all([
  getGdriveList(...),
  getGdriveList(...),
  getGdriveList(...),
]);

// more code ...
```