# wait for many files to download in parallel and continue

Tags: node.js, file, async-await

I am trying to download many files in parallel in node.
the problem is that since it is asynchronous I have to wait until all of them download and then continue with the program.
I want to be asynchronous since there are like 100 files to download and at the same time I have to wait all of them to be downloaded to continue with the program.

```
//pseudocode
for(1..100) {
  downloadFilesAsync()
}
//wait for the downloads to finish
continueSynchronously()
```

I cant add an 'await' in the downloadFilesAsync because this way it would wait for all of them secuentially and I don´t know how to wait for all of them once all of them have been downloaded

Comment: Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: should I save the values of the calls in a list and call it on the list?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and its answers.