# Does executing sync code in the same Promise.all as async code have any performance benefit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have a piece of middleware. It gets reports on data from 3 different endpoints in a Promise.all as its first step.

```
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const getDataFromEndpoint = async (key) => { 
  return await ... ;
};

const [result1, result2, result3] = await Promise.all(keys.map(key => getDataFromEndpoint(key)));
```

No questions here, using Promise.all as expected.

Then, in step 2, it gets another report from another endpoint. It also has to merge the data together from the first step, in a somewhat hefty synchronous operation.

EDIT: Switched the order so the async function is called first

```
const mergeResults = (arrayOfResults) => {
  return arrayOfResults.reduce( ... );
};

const anotherKey = 'd';

const [result4, mergedResults] = Promise.all([
  getDataFromEndpoint(anotherKey),
  mergeResults([result1, result2, result3]),
]);
```

Does this effectively run the sync code "while" the async call is waiting for a response? If so, is that more performant than not including the sync code in a Promise.all?

I have implemented it using Promise.all with a sync and async function, I just don't know if it made a difference or not.

Comment: _"does it even make sense"_... no, not really. `mergeResult()` will block starting `getDataFromEndpoint(anotherKey)` anyway.

Comment: @Phil Ah ok. What if I changed the order so getDataFromEndpoint fired first, and mergeResult happened second? Would it be executing the sync code "while" the async call returned?

Comment: In short, my question is unanswered and I disagree with it being closed, because I am asking something distinct from whether sync code has a benefit in Promise.all. I'm asking if there is a benefit executing sync code in a Promise.all where there is already async code being actioned. If you feel the same, try asking yourself.

Comment: Remember that it's _only async_, it's _not parallel_: all you're doing with async/await is telling JS how it's allowed to time-slices execution within a single thread. The `await` keyword signals that JS is allowed to interrupt execution at this point, but the _total amount of work_ that gets done is identical between async and non-async code. There is no "two things running at the same time" (for the parts that run in JS, at least. Obviously sending out 100 network requests without waiting for one to finish before running the next will be much slower than a Promise.all with 100 requests)

Comment: @GorgonFreeman is there a reason you can't make the 4th `getDataFromEndpoint()` until after the first 3 are resolved?

Comment: @Phil yes - the data from the 4th endpoint changes quickly, and if it's out of date it causes issues, so I want to use it as close to fetching it as possible. The first 3 calls  are not time-sensitive.

Comment: That sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You cannot reliably solve this by trying to exactly time the HTTP requests.

Comment: @Phil ah yeah, interesting. I think I'm in a good place doing the three first, which can take as long as they like, then leaving fetch the fourth until later, I was just wondering if including that sync operation in the Promise.all would be a further optimisation and shave off whatever time it would take doing it after the fourth data fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this effectively run the sync code "while" the async call is waiting for a response?

Sort of.

`getDataFromEndpoint(anotherKey)` will begin it's work and execute in the main thread up to its first async operation. Then control flow will pass to the next main thread operation `mergeResults([result1, result2, result3])`.

The main thread will be blocked while that completes and the array you're passing to `Promise.all()` won't be realised until then.

> is that more performant than not including the sync code in a Promise.all?

Without seeing any reason to delay the 4th `getDataFromEndpoint()` call, it would make more sense to perform all the async data fetching in parallel, await the results then merge them

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const results = await Promise.all([...keys, 'd'].map(getDataFromEndpoint));

const result4 = results.pop();
const mergedResults = mergeResults(results);
```

This approach makes the best use of concurrency and removes tricky issues around error handling (see comments below)

---

If delaying the fourth request is vital, I would just do it last after merging the first three

```js
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const mergedResults = mergeResults(
  await Promise.all(keys.map(getDataFromEndpoint)),
);

const anotherKey = "d";
const result4 = await getDataFromEndpoint(anotherKey);
```

Comment: [Don't do that though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation), it'll crash your application.

Comment: Not exactly obvious, but: If `p4` is getting rejected and `mergeResults` throws a (synchronous) exception, `try`/`catch` will be able to catch that exception but the promise rejection is unhandled and crashes your application. That's why this pattern is frowned upon. When creating a promise, always immediately `await` it or pass it to `Promise.all` and `await` that.

Comment: @Bergi interesting, I did not know that. Sort of why I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864260/does-executing-sync-code-in-the-same-promise-all-as-async-code-have-any-performa/77951996?noredirect=1#comment137425416_77864260) though

Comment: @Bergi in testing, using `Promise.all([getDataFromEndpoint('d'), mergeResults(results)])` makes no difference to the error handling. Once the synchronous code throws an error, any uncaught async errors go uncaught

Comment: Yes, it would need to be `new Promise(resolve => resolve(mergeResults(results)))` or `Promise.resolve(results).then(mergeResults)` to catch that error and bring it into the `Promise.all`. Or call the synchronous code strictly before the `await` or strictly after the `await`.

Comment: @Bergi it's really messy. Definitely feels like the better approach would be to fetch all data before doing the merge

Comment: @phil thanks for your input! In this case the data I'm fetching fourth is realtime and changes quickly, while the first three can take as long as they like - I'm trying to avoid the fourth response getting stale if one of the three takes much longer.

Comment: @GorgonFreeman I still don't think that's the optimal solution but in any case, you can ensure the _freshest_ data by performing the 4th request after everything else

Comment: Ok - I'm going to dwell on this for a while. Cheers!