# nodejs - Chaining dependent asynchrous operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have two asynchronous operations such that the invocation of the second one uses input from the output of the first. To implement such invocations with `async` and `await`, it seems, it won't turn out to be too different from callbacks.

Consider this.

```js
async function loop(label, I) {
    console.log('%s - Looping for %d times.', label, I)
    console.time(label)
    for (i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
    }
    return Promise.resolve(I)
}
//
async function demo0() {
    // Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479579/919480
    let I0 = loop('01', 10)
    let I1 = loop('02', I0 * 1000)
    await I0
    await I1
}
//
async function demo1() {
    // Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479579/919480
    let I0 = loop('11', 10)
    await I0
    let I1 = loop('12', I0 * 1000)
    await I1
}
//
async function demo2() {
    await loop('21', 10).then(async (i) => {
        await loop('22', i * 1000)
    })
}
//
(async () => {
    await demo0()
    await demo1()
    await demo2()
})()
```

Result:

```sh
01 - Looping for 10 times.
02 - Looping for NaN times.
11 - Looping for 10 times.
12 - Looping for NaN times.
21 - Looping for 10 times.
22 - Looping for 10000 times.
```

The second loop should iterate based on a value passed on by the first loop. In `demo0` and `demo1`, the second loop receives a `NaN` because they are triggered simultaneously. Only in `demo2`, does the second loop receive the correct value. One could have achieved this behavior with callbacks too.

Is there a `async/await` way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every call of an `async` function gives you a Promise in return, but Promises can't be (sensibly) added to numbers, so you get `NaN` in return.

If you want to be able to use the result of a Promise, you should `await` it *and use the resulting expression*. If you `await` the Promise and then try to use the original Promise, you'll still have a Promise, not a value, so you should assign the `await`ed Promise to a variable, eg change

```
let I0 = loop('01', 10)
let I1 = loop('02', I0 * 1000)
await I0
await I1
```

to

```
let I0 = loop('01', 10)
const resolveValueI0 = await I0;
let I1 = loop('02', resolveValueI0 * 1000)
await I1
```

(you cannot call the second `loop` until `I0` is done, because the second `loop` *needs* the number from the resolution of `I0`'s Promise. Either that, or pass the Promise to `I1`, and have `I1` properly consume it with `.then` or `await`)

and

```
let I0 = loop('11', 10)
await I0
let I1 = loop('12', I0 * 1000)
await I1
```

to

```
let I0 = loop('11', 10)
const resolveValueI0 = await I0;
let I1 = loop('12', resolveValueI0 * 1000)
await I1
```

```js
async function loop(label, I) {
    console.log('%s - Looping for %d times.', label, I)
    console.time(label)
    for (i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
    }
    return Promise.resolve(I)
}
//
async function demo0() {
    // Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479579/919480
    let I0 = await loop('01', 10)
    let I1 = loop('02', I0 * 1000)
    await I0
    await I1
}
//
async function demo1() {
    // Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479579/919480
    let I0 = loop('11', 10)
    const result = await I0
    let I1 = loop('12', result * 1000)
    await I1
}
//
async function demo2() {
    await loop('21', 10).then(async (i) => {
        await loop('22', i * 1000)
    })
}
//
(async () => {
    await demo0()
    await demo1()
    await demo2()
})()
```

Comment: hmm...yes, I missed the one about the `Promise` _resolution_. Nevertheless, this is another option too, right? `let I0 = await loop('01', 10); let I1 = await loop('02', I0 * 1000)`.

Comment: Yes, and that's actually the preferred option, as long as it doesn't confuse you - fewer unnecessary variables is usually a good thing.